# Root view controller's view disappears when pushing another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am trying to push a `UIViewController` on my `UINavigationController`'s root view controller. I am doing this with a custom transition to make it look like a modal presentation.

```
CATransition* trans = [CATransition animation];
trans.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
trans.duration = 0.4f;
trans.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:trans forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

My problem is, that the `self` view controller's view seems to disappear when I push, so the background behind the modal-presentation becomes black while the transition runs.

This image illustrates the problem:
[image]

When the transtition is done the magenta view is visible as expected, but while the transition occurs the green background disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using iOS 7, you should use the new custom transition protocols to deal with this instead of animating the layers yourself. The problem is that the navigation controller is immediately updating the view model as soon as you call push since you told it not to animate, removing the previous view from the screen—and possibly the view hierarchy all together.

Comment: It is correct. UINavigationController works in a way that when you push new view controller without animation it immediately shows new  view and hide previous view.

There are two proper ways to accomplished it:
1) use new custom transition protocols,
2) create your own container view controller instead of using uinavigationcontroller. This new container will be responsible for changing & animating of child view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDuration:0.40];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionReveal];

        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];

        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

        [navController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
        [navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```